# Grunt task to only compile newer scss files with node-sass

Tags: gruntjs, node-sass

I have a few scss entrypoints (main.scss) which import other scss files with `@import "components/popup"`.

Directory structure is as followed:

```
scss
    main.scss
        components
            _popup.scss
            _carousel.scss

otherScssDir
    main.scss
        components
            _datepicker.scss
            _dropdown.scss
```

When watching for changes on all my scss files with [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch), *both* the entrypoints (main.scss) will be compiled to css. It would be ideal to only compile entrypoints where the imported scss files have been changed.

I'm using [grunt-newer](https://github.com/tschaub/grunt-newer) to check if files have been changed.

Is it possible to do this? A nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it is but your question doesn't exactly make sense.  Can you please reword it to clarify better as to what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Do all your main files generate separate css files as output or are they merged. How does your scss task config look like.

Comment: @Vishwanath all the main files have separate output files. I'll add my Gruntfile asap but I don't have access to it at the moment.